# How to reflect dropped tables from models in the database using Sequelize commands?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I currently call a custom function `dbinit()` in terminal whenever I have updated my models and want my database to reflect those changes. This function includes the Sequelize method `db.sequelize.sync()`, which adds some changes to my database including new tables and columns.

Unfortunately, `sync()` doesn't remove tables from the database to reflect changes in my model. Is there some code I can add to my custom function that will make the database reflect tables that have been deleted?

(using PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and Node.js 5.1.0)

Comment: How are you deleting your tables? Use the [drop](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#drop) function.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to write a more universal function that I can call whenever I update the models in my `models/Model.js` files.

Right now I have to go into sql and drop tables manually using `drop` like you're suggesting. But I'd rather just add some text to my custom `dbinit()` function, so I can call it from the command line and have Sequelize update the database itself, if possible!